# capability of + adj +adv

Tags: english-to-german

I am doubting how to translate the following sentence correct:

> It has the *capability of democratizing space technologies, making* them accessible for the first time to a wide variety of users, ranging from universities to small companies

The difficult part for me is: *capability of democratizing space technologies, making*. I tried translating it as follows:

> Es hat die Fähigkeit, Weltraumtechnologien zu demokratisieren um erstmals einer Vielzahl von Nutzern zugänglich zu machen …

But I have found the noun *Demokratisieren* for *democratizing* and decided to rewrite it as:

> Es hat die Demokratisierenfähigkeit der Weltraumtechnologien um erstmals einer Vielzahl von Nutzern zugänglich zu machen …

What do you think about my translation? Could readers understand my sentence?

Comment: The title doesn't comply with the actual question. There is no adjective and no adverb in the phrase in question.

Comment: @Björn Friedrich correct, this question is rather about translating the English gerund.

Comment: I'm struggling with the meaning of your sentence. *Demokratisierung* in the more narrow sense means making something a democracy, which is clearly not meant here. In the broader sense it means a kind of proliferation, but then *making it accessible to a wide range* is exactly the same thing. So the sentence would boil down to: *Es kann Weltraumtechnologien erstmals einer breiten Öffentlichkeit zugänglich machen*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first choice of translation is better as it doesn't use the 'Nominalstil'. But it is missing a 'sie' / 'diese' or an 'und'. Two possibilities:

> Es hat die Fähigkeit, Weltraumtechnologien zu demokratisieren, um *sie* erstmals einer Vielzahl von Nutzern zugänglich zu machen …

> Dies bietet die Möglichkeit, Raumfahrttechnologien zu demokratisieren und zum ersten Mal einer Vielzahl an Nutzern zugänglich zu machen, angefangen bei Universitäten bis hin zu Kleinunternehmen.

If you feel like using nouns, the word would be 'Demokratisierung' or the complete expression 'Es bietet die Fähigkeit zur Demokratisierung'. A compound word 'Demokratisierungsfähigkeit' is possible, but not nice.

Last but not least: Think about making it shorter sentences to enhance comprehension:

> Dies bietet die Möglichkeit Raumfahrttechnologien zu demonkratisieren. Damit werden diese zum ersten Mal einer Vielzahl von Nutzern, von Universitäten bis zu Kleinstunternehmen, zugänglich gemacht.

Comment: @Björn can you explain why you think that a change of 'nice/er' to better/good is an improvement? (I disagree as it gives a slightly different tone than I intend)

Comment: I assumed that you wanted to say *[...] ist schöner* and *[...] aber nicht schön*. However, the main meaning of *nice* is *nett/ freundlich*. Therefore, I would interpret the original phrases *[...] is nicer* and *[...] but not nice* as *[...] ist netter* and *[...] aber nicht nett*.